# setBackgroundResource calls android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources

I have `btn_solve_selector.xml` file in Drawable folder in order to set `Button` background programatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

With above code, I coded below code in `onCreate` of `MyActivity`.

```
    _button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_solve_selector);
```

But the app was crashed with followed stacktrace.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/btn_solvenow_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020085
....
at com.MyPackage.MyActivity.setMode(MyActivity.java:343)
....
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
....
```

It seems like the drawable xml file is failed to read even the file has `<item />` inside of it and then fall-back to read android.content.res as a second trial. (I even checked with `com.MyPackage.R.drawable.btn_solve_selector` instead but failed).

I removed and reinstalled the app but failed. What am I missing?

Comment: Simply, the above `_button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_solve_selector);` code was placed in onCreate().

Comment: you can apply background to button using android:background="@drawable/btn_solve_selector" for button the layout xml file.

Comment: @SharadMhaske // thanks for reply, the button background needs to be changed with some modes in my app.

Comment: @Youngjae:check my edited code hope that will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this-

```
    <selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#E51400"
                android:endColor="#E51400"
                />
              <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
              <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />

                <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="4dp" />

        </shape>
</item>

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#4AA038"
                android:endColor="#72C437"
               />

             <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />

             <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
               <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="4dp" />

        </shape>
</item>



</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `android:drawable` instead of `android:color` in your selector xml file, it works for me.

Try cleaning the project too

Comment: Sorry to change the answer flag. Sharad gives the solution with pure xml content. (and I upvote yours)

Comment: Best answer, but there's a little more to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17701589/507339 - Still not as much XML as Mhaske's answer.

Comment: @AAnkit I'm too facing the same problem, I applied answer given by "Sharad Mhaske" but no luck and as told by you, I use android:drawable instead of android:color, even this too didn't worked, I'm getting same error. Any Ideas on how to resolve this, on android 4.4 upwards, the same code works but in android 2.3 v10, this error get encountered.

Comment: I will have to look at your code. Can you create a question, post code there, post link here, I will look at it.