# Exception android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/my.xml from drawable resource ID

Tags: android, android-layout

Whats wrong with this xml, I am trying to get a button press feel. I am getting a exception, I am unable to understood. `ResourceNotFound`

In my layout.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/submitbuttonpress"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textColor="#eeeee4"
    android:typeface="monospace" />
```

My submitbuttonpress.xml in the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:background="#AAAAAA" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:background="#777777" />
</selector>
```

Exception (logcat)

```
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.taxeeta/com.itaxeeta.BookingExperience}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #326: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #326: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:216)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1660)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.itaxeeta.BookingExperience.onCreate(BookingExperience.java:100)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 11 more
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 27 more
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/nextprevbuttonpress.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003e
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:389)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 30 more
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:167)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
07-17 19:07:25.072: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 35 more
```

Comment: You cannot stick a raw colour string into your `<item>` like that. You need to create shape drawables for each state and reference those in your selector using `android:drawable`. Check the valid attributes for `<item>` here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Thanks, yes it was also on the exception, dont know why I missed it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Once Try this

In selector state it is required to add drawable and in your case you wants to add color in selector state.So it is possible to create drawable using color in resource. It will work as `ColorDrawable`

Please check below code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/clr_normal" android:state_pressed="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/clr_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    </selector>
```

values/string.xml for color

```
 <drawable name="clr_normal">#AAAAAA</drawable>
<drawable name="clr_pressed">#777777</drawable>
```

Comment: To late to the party, I was using bitmap in shape drawable which I replaced with item `drawable` property of an item. This fixed my issue, btw I had vector drawable

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `android:background` does not exist. The correct way to do this is to first create a new resource file `res/colors.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="lt_gray">#AAAAAA</color>
    <color name="dk_gray">#777777</color>
</resources>
```

Then just change your `selector` to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/lt_gray" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dk_gray" />
</selector>
```

This automatically creates a [ColorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) and assigns it as the drawable for that state.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work if you give hex color to `android:drawable`. You should instead create a `color` attribute in `style.xml` or `strings.xml` and then give the color name to android:drawable like so :  
`android:drawable="@color/bg_color"`

Comment: I get a lint error 'color attribute should be defined'